# Terraform create variable array from tfvars

Tags: arrays, variables, terraform

I am still getting used to using Terraform and have the following question.

I have an array in a TFVARS file;
`extproviders = [ "production" , "support" ]`

i am using thisto call a module

```
module userpoolclientN {
   count = length(var.extproviders)
   source =  "../modules/cognito"
   basename = var.extproviders[count.index]
}
```

what i would like to do is create a new array that attaches 'odd' 'even' to each variable.
I dont want the user to input this as the extproviders is used elsewhere in the code.

```
extproviders_new = [ "production_odd" ,"production_even" , "support_odd", "support_even" ]


module userpoolclientN {
   count = length(var.extproviders_new)
   source =  "../modules/cognito"
   basename = var.extproviders_new[count.index]
}
```

I am still learning Terraform, understand i cant use a for loop to accomplish this.
Is there another way?

Comment: Would you consider updating the usage to `for_each` so that the `for` expression can be used directly as the module argument (also could then remove `basename` argument)? It would simplify and stabilize the usage and answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `for` and `foreach` :

```
variable "extproviders" {
  default = ["production", "support"]
}

locals {
  extproviders_new  = flatten([ for e in var.extproviders : tolist(["${e}odd","${e}even"])])
}


module userpoolclientN {
   for_each = toset(local.extproviders_new)
   source =  "../modules/cognito"
   basename = each.value
}
```

Explaining the `locals` :

> For each element on the input list returns a list made of that element + odd suffix and element + even suffix.
> Then flatten those list into a single one

[flatten()](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/flatten) will transform multilevel lists into a single one

[[for]](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/for) will returns a list containing two [lists](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/list)

`"${e}odd"` and `"${e}even"` is a simple string concatenation